# Can I simplify this code? And if so how

Tags: c#, simplification

I am trying to add multiple commands to my very first MVVM program.
But the way I am adding them here feels wrong to me.
I want to prevent as much duplication as possible, can I make a kind of parent command that I can easily modify for example?

```
internal class AddTimerBarCommand : ICommand
{
    public AddTimerBarCommand(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _MainViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    private MainViewModel _MainViewModel;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _MainViewModel.AddTimerBar();
    }
}

internal class RmvTimerBarCommand : ICommand
{
    public RmvTimerBarCommand(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _MainViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    private MainViewModel _MainViewModel;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _MainViewModel.RmvTimerBar();
    }
```

Comment: Are you using any MVVM Framework (ex.: MVVM Light)?

Comment: I am not, I read some articles on MVVM and watched some vids, and am now trying to wrap my head around it all. I think I understand the general gist of it. why?

Comment: Give a look at my answer :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for a base class to reduce code duplication?

If so, this might work for you:

```
internal abstract class TimerBarCommandBase : ICommand
{
    public TimerBarCommandBase(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _MainViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    protected MainViewModel _MainViewModel;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return true; }

    public abstract void Execute(object parameter);
}

internal class AddTimerBarCommand : TimerBarCommandBase
{
    public AddTimerBarCommand(MainViewModel viewModel) : base(viewModel) { }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _MainViewModel.AddTimerBar();
    }
}

internal class RmvTimerBarCommand : TimerBarCommandBase
{
    public RmvTimerBarCommand(MainViewModel viewModel) : base(viewModel) { }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _MainViewModel.RmvTimerBar();
    }
}
```

Comment: very interesting, I did not know I could base constructors on parent constructors. I will play with this

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Enigmativity is good since you asked for a way to optimize your code.

But, in MVVM, when it comes to using `ICommand`, normally we use a `RelayCommand` that is implemented in the MVVM Framework used for the project.

Here is a [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx) written by Laurent Bugnion the developer of MVVM Light. Using this, you won't have to create a new class every time you want to bind a command and therefore will "prevent as much duplication as possible".